# Memory leak using a class method

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a problem with my program : I have a memory leak. I know it because when I look at the memory usage it never stop increasing, and then the program crash.

I have remarked that it happens because of this line (when I comment it there is no problem) :

```
replica[n].SetTempId(i+1); // FUITE MEMOIRE SUR CETTE LIGNE !!
```

I have checked that n is never bigger than the size of my array (which is a vector type, see below).

My class :

```
class Replica
{
    /* All the functions in this class are in the 'public:' section */
    public:
        Replica();
        ~Replica();
        void SetEnergy(double E);
        void SetConfName(string config_name);
        void SetTempId(int id_temp);
        int GetTempId();
        string GetConfName();
        double GetEnergy();
        void SetUp();
        void SetDown();
        void SetZero();
        int GetUpDown();   

    /* All the attributes in this class are in the 'private:' section */
    private:
        double m_E; // The energy of the replica
        string m_config_name; // The name of the config file associated
        int m_id_temp; // The id of the temperature where the spin configuration is.
        int m_updown;
};
```

The method

```
void Replica::SetTempId(int id_temp)
{
    m_id_temp=id_temp;
}
```

I initialised my object like this :

```
vector<Replica> replica(n_temp); // we create a table that will contain information on the replicas.
```

The constructor :

```
Replica::Replica() : m_E(0), m_config_name(""), m_updown(0), m_id_temp(0)
{

}
```

How I initialize my vector :

```
for(int i=0; i<=n_temp-1 ; i++) // We write the object replica that will contain information on a given spin configuration.
                {
                    string temp_folder="";
                    temp_folder= spin_folder +  "/T=" + to_string(Tf[i]) + ".dat";
                    replica[i].SetEnergy(Ef[i]+i); // we save the energy of the config (to avoid to calculate it)
                    replica[i].SetConfName(temp_folder); // we save the name of the file where the config is saved (to avoid to have huge variables that will slow down the program)
                    replica[i].SetTempId(i);
                    replica[i].SetZero();
                    if(i==0)
                        replica[i].SetDown();
                    if(i==(n_temp-1))
                        replica[i].SetUp();
                }
```

I am a beginner in C++ so it is probably a basic mistake.

Thank you for your help !

---

I have read your answers.

But it is hard to write a minimal code : I tried to delete some stuff but as soon as I delete lines it works.

In fact the problem is very "random", for example when I delete my line :

```
replica[n].SetTempId(i+1);
```

it works, but I can have this line not deleted but when I delete an other line of my code it will also works (I dont know if you see what I mean).
The bug is very hard to find because of this "randomness"...

I also can say that when it crash the program says me :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'


 what():  std::bad_alloc
```

So, could you give me guess on what could cause this error (because I don't arrive to write the minimal code).

I don't do dynamic allocation on my code.

---

The structure of my code is like this :

```
while(Nsw_c<Nsw)
        {
cout << "test1";
         // a 
// lot
// of
// code
// with some Nsw_c++
    // and this cout at the end of the loop
         cout << " Nsw_c : " << Nsw_c << endl << " i " << i << " compteur_bug " << compteur_bug;
        }


cout << "test2";
```

It ALWAYS freeze on this cout above which is at the end of the loop.

I know this because neither test2 or test1 are displayed when it freezes and it is the next cout.

Nsw, Nsw_c, i are integers that are lower than 100 (they are not too big).

To be more precise, if I replace the cout just at the end of the loop by another cout like this :

```
cout << " test ";
```

It will also freeze at the same place.

In fact the program always freeze at the end of my while (juste before analysing the condition).

But Nsw and Nsw_c are not big at all so that's why it is strange.

I tried to replace the condition Nsw_c < Nsw just by "1" and it didn't freeze anymore. So it is probably a problem with the condition but both are just "normal" integers so...

Thanks !

---

I have launched gdb (i just learnt to use it) and i wrote :

catch throw std::bad_alloc

The debugger then do this (I don't know if it can help) :

not stopped at a C++ exception catchpoint
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), 0xb7f25290 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: With the code you posted it should not be possible to have a memory leak as they are all RAII types.

Comment: There are no calls to `new` or `delete` in the code you posted.  You should post a [mcve], as we really don't know the entire picture of where this vector is being created.  For example, we don't know if the vector is really a member in a class, and instances of *that* class is where the deallocation is not occurring.

Comment: Where are you instantiating your object before setting values to your member variables?

Comment: Where is the value of n_temp assigned? It's possible, although probably unlikely, that this value is large enough where it's causing too much memory to be allocated.

Comment: n_temp is not very large, it is around 100.

My object is only initialized like this : vector<Replica> replica(n_temp); (it use the default constructor when I do this, right ?)

Also, When it crashes, in fact it is very strange because it always freeze on this cout :

cout << " Nsw_c : " << Nsw_c << endl << " te " << te << " compteur_bug " << compteur_bug;

It never freeze anywhere else (I know it freeze exactly here because this cout is at the end of a while and it never go to the next instruction (which is also a cout)

Nsw_c and te are int (and they are not large at all, int lower than 100

Comment: (See the end of the message for further information about how it freezes)

Comment: Are you using a vector function to add objects to replica ?  replica.push_back(new Replica(...));